# Can I use IntelliTest to generate sensible unit-tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, intellitest

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/generate-unit-tests-for-your-code-with-intellitest) for IntelliTest says:

> IntelliTest explores your .NET code to generate test data and a suite of unit tests. For every statement in the code, a test input is generated that will execute that statement. A case analysis is performed for every conditional branch in the code. For example, `if` statements, assertions, and all operations that can throw exceptions are analyzed. This analysis is used to generate test data for a parameterized unit test for each of your methods, creating unit tests with high code coverage.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I right-clicked inside my method, selected "IntelliTest" and then "Create IntelliTest". I accepted all the defaults on the pop-up dialogue box and clicked "OK".

```
    public static int ScanInternalInbox()
    {
        if (<code removed>)
        {
            <code removed>;
        }

        <code removed>;

        try
        {
            <code removed>;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            <code removed>;
            return 0;
        }

        <code removed>;

        try
        {
            <code removed>;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            <code removed>;
        }

        <code removed>;
        foreach (<code removed>)
        {
            <code removed>;

            if (<code removed>)
            {
                if (<code removed>)
                {
                    <code removed>;

                    if (<code removed>)
                    {
                        foreach (<code removed>)
                        {
                            <code removed>;
                            if (<code removed>)
                            {
                                if (<code removed>)
                                {
                                    <code removed>;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (<code removed>)
                        {
                            if (<code removed>)
                            {
                                <code removed>;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <code removed>;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <code removed>;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    <code removed>;
                }                    
            }
            else
            {
                <code removed>;
            }
        }

        <code removed>;
    }
```

Why then, does my method with many, many (too many) `if`s just generate this unit-test code?

```
public partial class HMR_AgentTest {

  /// <summary>Test stub for ScanInternalInbox()</summary>
  [PexMethod]
  public int ScanInternalInboxTest() {
    int result = global::HMR_Agent.HMR_Agent.ScanInternalInbox();
    return result;
    // TODO: add assertions to method HMR_AgentTest.ScanInternalInboxTest()
  }
}
```

I expected to get at least one test for each `if`, to cover the code (almost) completely. Did I do something wrong? Is there a way to generate default tests the way Microsoft claims?

#### EDIT

I've now Run IntelliTest too, and it has generated the following code:

```
  public partial class HMR_AgentTest {

[TestMethod]
[PexGeneratedBy(typeof(HMR_AgentTest))]
[PexRaisedException(typeof(TypeInitializationException))]
public void ScanInternalInboxTestThrowsTypeInitializationException908()
{
    int i;
    i = this.ScanInternalInboxTest();
    Assert.AreEqual<int>(-1, i);
}
  }
```

The test fails because an Exception is thrown, even though the test expects an Exception to be thrown.

Comment: Where is your code that is to be tested? Can you please add it to your question.

Comment: I just logged a defect for this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/162084/unit-tests-fail-for-argumentnullexception-despite.html

Intellitest just has too many problems and issues that make using it not worth the burden of dealing with the problems.

Answer (score 0):

The `[PexMethod]` effectively just identifies the function you want to test.  You need to right click and "IntelliTest -> Run IntelliTest" on the PexMethod for the first time to generate a child `.g.cs` file that contains tests for all paths of execution.

You "Run IntelliTest" again only when you make changes to the code that changes execution paths or alters the behavior; if you're just refactoring code, you don't need to generate new test code, you just run the generated `[TestMethod]` tests in the `g.cs` file as normal.

Comment: Running the generated test does not check to see if the exception was expected.